# Given two unsigned char variables, assign the lowest 4 bits of A to be highest 4 bits of B, and the highest 4 bits of A to be the lowest 4 bits of B

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Forgive me if this is a duplicate, however I need someone to explain to me how to accomplish the following (the bitwise masking/shifting in C confuses me)

From what I understand I need to switch the first 4 bits with the last 4 bits, but I am unsure how to do so.

This is a question taken from a Midterm Exam that has been posted for Review/Study purposes

Question:

I have declared two unsigned char variables, a and b.  Assume that a has been initialized. I would like to assign a value to b such that the lowest four bits of a are the highest four bits of b and the highest four bits of a are the lowest four bits of b.

Write a single line of C code that will accomplish this.

And if you can, explain it to me so I can better understand what is going on, thank you.

Comment: assignment? what have you done so far?

Comment: @codekaizer It's a question on a midterm review, I am not even sure where to start

Comment: @ScarletsFeed we can't really help you with school questions, but I'll try my best to explain to you how.

Comment: formulate and solve a [simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem) first. Can you do this on more than one line? Can you assign any bits from `a` to `b`? Do you know how to use [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)?

Comment: You need to try more than just rewording the question.  Where's your code that attempts to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- extract the 4 low order bits of `a` with `a & 0x0F`
- shift them left by 4 with the `<<` operator
- extract the 4 high order bits of `a` with `a & 0xF0`
- shift these right by 4 to bring them to the low order position with `>>`
- combine these results with `|`.
- add some parentheses to ensure correct precedence